# browser stripping src attribute from img for unknown reason

Tags: html, attributes

Can anyone offer any insight as to why in the source of a webpage, an  tag would have a 'src' attribute', but in the inspector and rendered page the 'src' attribute and its source url is removed? I copy and pasted the raw output and pasted it into the page and it worked, as well as disabled js in case that was the issue.

```
<img alt="Facebook" title="Share on Facebook" class="synved-share-image synved-social-image synved-social-image-share" width="24" height="24" style="display: inline; width:24px;height:24px; margin: 0; padding: 0;border: none; box-shadow: none;" src="http://www.site.devv/wp-content/themes/site/assets/images/SocialIcons/ShareIcons/24x24/facebook.png"/>
```

Inspector/Rendered page

`<img alt="Facebook" title="Share on Facebook" class="synved-share-image synved-social-image synved-social-image-share" width="24" height="24" style="display: inline; width:24px;height:24px; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; box-shadow: none;">`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Try `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`. Alternatively the image may not actually exist, and your browser is simply saving itself from rendering a dead imagine.

Comment: Thanks Obsidian, but I emptied the cache, and checked the URL, and the link is good

Comment: Could you provide us with a sample page where that happens?

Comment: I unfortunately can't as it's a staging site for a client who has not launched the site yet

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer. It turns out the social sharing plugin was creating a duplicate set of elements that had icons for retina, and it was looking for icons in a different folder for 48x48 (which didn't exist, hence no src) and hiding the 24x24 icons.